# Swift - placing TableView below another view with constraints programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I am using Swift 4.2.

I am trying to get a tableview below another view, for example - label.

What I want is something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|        label                           |
+----------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------+
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|        tableView                       |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
+----------------------------------------+

// label constraints
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let label_Leading_Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let label_Trailing_Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let label_Top_Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: previous_label, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label_Leading_Constraint, label_Trailing_Constraint, label_Top_Constraint])


var tableView = UITableView()
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false      
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")

self.view.addSubview(tableView)

tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
```

When I use the above code, the tableview is shown. The tableview constraints are relatively to the ALL view (self.view) which is not what I want because, I want the tableview to appear below the label.

If I change this code to my desired code (the top of the tableview should be 20 below the label view):

```
tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
```

I get the label view messed up at the bottom of the screen and the tableview is not showing at all.

Please don't suggest a table header of something like that. You can assume I have some more views in the top section of the screen and I simply want the tableview to be shown below them.

Also, please don't suggest the storyboard. I am trying to do it all programmatically.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post `label`s anchors as well ?

Comment: @Olympiloutre label constraints are added

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes. I have series of labels, one below the other. Before I added the table view, everything looked fine. I just can't get the table view below label.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Actually, the labels are inside a stack view. The tableview should be below the stack view.

Comment: So we need to see the `stackview` constraints.

Comment: @Olympiloutre those are the same constraints i used for "label". Just take label as a stack view.

Comment: `let label_Top_Constraint = ...` 
why `NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom` ?
Bear in mind that for us to figure out where your layout fails, we need to see the global picture... which means all the constraints you set and all relation between your views

Comment: @Olympiloutre because you want to place label's top 20 pixels below previous_label's bottom.

Comment: I thought I should consider the Labels constraints as the stackview's ones. 
Post your full layout code otherwise noting makes sens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194140/discussion-between-aj-gottes-and-olympiloutre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your `UILabel`s constraint are not set properly.

for instance if you have set `label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true` this would lead to the "messed up" result you are getting.

The labels anchors should be :

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false      
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
```

and nothing more

Comment: You were right! one of the views didn't have constraint which caused the other vertical views that came right after it, to mess up. It's all about constraints! Thanks!